# Proper way to structure my REST api in this case

Tags: rest, mean-stack

I am trying to build a little web application with the MEAN stack (MongoDB, ExpressJS, AngularJS and NodeJS).

My question is very simple. If you take the example of a blog, it will contains blog posts, that you could list at this url:

GET /api/posts

You could also get the comments for that posts:

GET /api/posts/:postId/comments

and get a single comment:

GET /api/posts/:postId/comments/:commentId

The relation between post and comment is really obvious here, but does it still makes it mandatory to have it this way? or could I just perform my CRUD operations through /api/comments? In the end, a comment object in mongodb will always have a postId attribute anyway which will reference the post that it is related to... Moreover, the API will not be exposed and is strictly meant to be used by the application.

Answer (score 0):

> does it still makes it mandatory to have it this way?

No. This is not mandatory at all.

> or could I just perform my CRUD operations through /api/comments?

Yes. This will result in cleaner resources URIs (endpoints).

#### You can also get post-specific comments with:

```
GET /api/comments?postId={postId}
```

Further, you could also drop the `/api` prefix if you are serving only an API at the given host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how would I list the comments on a specific blog post then? /api/comments/:postId ? Does this makes sense?